# Escaping a regex after finding the first occurance

Tags: regex

I have the following code in my database:

```
[tab title="Smart Player"]
[videojs mp4="http://webiste.com/video.mp4"]
[/tab]

[tab title="Gvideo Player"]

[videojs_video url="https://example.com/open?id=0B5i7u5TAodOFa0JmVGo2TDZjc1E"]

OR

[gvideojs gdid="0B5i7u5TAodOFa0JmVGo2TDZjc1E"]
[/tab]

[tab title="FV Player"]
[fvplayer src="http:/example.com/video.mp4" width="848" height="480"]
[/tab]

[tab title="Mp4 Player"]
<iframe src="https://sites.com" width="848" height="480" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
[/tab]

[tab title="Source 4"]

<iframe src="http://source.com/video1.mp4" width="848" height="480" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
[/tab]

[/tabs]
```

and I am looking to delete everything within the

> [tab title="Gvideo Player"]
>
> [/tab]
>   including the expressions above.

I have the following regex expression:

> (([tab title="Gvideo Player"])[\s\S]*([/tab]))

It starts correctly but it continues searching until the last [/tab]

Is it possible to stop the execution after finding only the first [/tab]

??

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `*?` operator. By default the `*` operator makes a greedy search. A `*?` makes it not greedy.

```
((\[tab title="Gvideo Player"\])[\s\S]*?(\[\/tab\]))
```

[I have edited your answer because my above code was wrong] Thank you for the help. It worked :-)